# openssh sftp server file permissions not being set by umask (but folder perms are)

Tags: file-permissions, sftp, umask

I am running the openssh sftp server like so:

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -u 002
```

And the folders I upload via sftp get these permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x 12 developer staff  4096 Dec 10 13:20 one
drwxrwxr-x  4 developer staff  4096 Dec 10 13:20 two
```

so far so good. However, uploaded files are not getting the right permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 developer staff  1406 Dec 10 13:20 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r--  1 developer staff  298  Dec 10 13:20 settings.json
```

I am connecting to the sftp server as the *developer* user with a script, so no permissions are being set by the client. Additionally, I have `umask 002` in the developers *~/.bashrc*.

I need the group to have write permissions to uploaded files.

Any idea on why this is not working?

Note: if I remove the `-u 002` flag from the sftp Subsystem, the folder permissions are *rwxr-xr-x*, which tells me that the `-u` flag is working.